# Copying data from an Excel sheet to Word

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

This code copies a specific range and a chart from an Excel sheet to Word. This code works fine but it is very slow. I have used `delays(Wait)` to work properly while dealing with clipboard copy-paste. If I don't use delays as error occurs.

This program copies 140 Excel-ranges and 140 charts, so it takes a lot of time. Any suggestions to make the program execute faster?

```
Sub ExcelToWord()
    Dim fileName, Pathname As String
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim mychart As ChartObject
    Pathname = "c:\Charts\"
    vArr = Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J")
    For Each vFile In vArr
        fileName = Dir(Pathname & vFile & "\" & "*.xlsx")
        Dim WdObj As Object
        Set WdObj = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        WdObj.Documents.Add
        'Loop for all files begins
        Do While fileName <> ""
            Set WB = Workbooks.Open(Pathname & vFile & "\" & fileName)
            ActiveSheet.Columns("C:C").Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            Dim rLastCell As Range
            Dim ColLtr As String
            Set rLastCell = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, Lookat:= _
            xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
            ColLtr = Replace(Cells(1, rLastCell.Column).Address(True, False), "$1", "")
            ActiveSheet.Columns(ColLtr).Copy
            ActiveSheet.Columns("C").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Dim lastrow As Long, lastcol As Long
            Dim rngTemp As Range
            With ActiveSheet
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
                    lastrow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                          MatchCase:=False).Row
                    lastcol = 3
                Else
                    lastrow = 1: lastcol = 1
                End If
                Set rngTemp = .Range("A1:" & Split(.Cells(, lastcol).Address, "$")(1) & lastrow)
                Set mychart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1)
            End With
            WdObj.Visible = True
            WdObj.Activate
            rngTemp.Select
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
            Selection.Copy
            DoEvents
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
            WdObj.Selection.PasteSpecial
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            mychart.Select
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
            Selection.Copy
            DoEvents
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
            WdObj.Selection.PasteSpecial
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Const wdPageBreak = 7
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
            WdObj.Selection.InsertBreak (wdPageBreak)
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            WB.Close SaveChanges:=False
            fileName = Dir()
        Loop
        Dim fname As String
        fname = "Converted and Combined.docx"
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        With WdObj
            .ChangeFileOpenDirectory "C:\Charts\" & vFile & "\"
            .ActiveDocument.SaveAs fileName:=fname
        End With
        With WdObj
            .ActiveDocument.Close
            .Quit
        End With
        Set WdObj = Nothing
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What error do you get and which line is highlighted?

Answer (score 6):

Things you could try:

1. Set shorter wait times. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1544582/2707864) shows you how. This is likely the main source of delay. You can assess if this is true by timing the total time, and calculating the time taken with each `vfile`.
2. Avoid `Select`ing unless mandatory. For instance, replace

   ```
   ActiveSheet.Columns("C").Select
   ActiveSheet.Paste
   ```

   with

   ```
   ActiveSheet.Columns("C").PasteSpecial
   ```

Answer (score 5):

One thing that takes a lot of time in VBA code is switching windows. I usually disable graphical updates with

```
Application.Screenupdating = false
```

at the top of my function, then

```
Application.Screenupdating = true
```

at the exit(s).

More details on this, [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193498.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Those waits will kill you. A second doesn't seem like much, until you stack a lot of them together. I don't think you need to set CutCopyMode to False until the very end, either.

What I would try is something like the following. Instead of this, which has two built-in wait periods:

```
rngTemp.Select
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
Selection.Copy
DoEvents
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
WdObj.Selection.PasteSpecial
```

I would use a loop to repeat the attempted paste until it has no error, something like this:

```
Do
    On Error Resume Next
    rngTemp.Copy
    DoEvents
    WdObj.Selection.PasteSpecial
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        On Error Goto 0
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
```

In fact, it seems to me that there isn't so much a problem with the copy as with the paste, so try this first:

```
rngTemp.Copy
DoEvents
Do
    On Error Resume Next
    WdObj.Selection.PasteSpecial
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        On Error Goto 0
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: I would format the last code segment as `On Error Resume Next`
`Do`
`    WdObj.Selection.PasteSpecial`
`    If Err.Number = 0 Then: Exit Do`
`Loop`
`On Error GoTo 0`
 to reduce the number of calls within the `Do`..`Loop`, and to increase readability - though admittedly, that last point is more of a personal preference

Comment: I think there was a reason I put the `On Error` calls inside rather than outside the loop, but I don't recall what it may have been.

Answer (score 3):

The following is a start at an answer to speed things up.

Basically, I have begun to replace all instances in which you individually `.select` and or reference the same object over and over(esp. `Activesheet`)

Take a look and compare to your version. Please note that I did not have a chance to run this:

```
Sub ExcelToWord()
    Dim fileName, Pathname As String
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim mychart As ChartObject
    Dim vArr
    Dim vFile
    Pathname = "c:\Charts\"
    vArr = Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J")
    For Each vFile In vArr
        fileName = Dir(Pathname & vFile & "\" & "*.xlsx")
        Dim WdObj As Object
        Set WdObj = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        WdObj.Documents.Add
        'Loop for all files begins
        Do While fileName <> ""
            Set WB = Workbooks.Open(Pathname & vFile & "\" & fileName)
            Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
            Set wks = WB.Worksheets(1)
            wks.Columns("C:C").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            Dim rLastCell As Range
            Dim ColLtr As String
            Set rLastCell = wks.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, Lookat:= _
            xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
            ColLtr = Replace(Cells(1, rLastCell.Column).Address(True, False), "$1", "")
            wks.Columns(ColLtr).Copy wks.Columns("C")
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Dim lastrow As Long, lastcol As Long
            Dim rngTemp As Range
            With wks
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
                    lastrow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                          MatchCase:=False).Row
                    lastcol = 3
                Else
                    lastrow = 1: lastcol = 1
                End If
                Set rngTemp = .Range("A1:" & Split(.Cells(, lastcol).Address, "$")(1) & lastrow)
                Set mychart = wks.ChartObjects(1)
            End With
            WdObj.Visible = True
            WdObj.Activate
            rngTemp.Select
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
            Selection.Copy
            DoEvents
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
            WdObj.Selection.PasteSpecial
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            mychart.Select
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
            Selection.Copy
            DoEvents
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
            WdObj.Selection.PasteSpecial
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Const wdPageBreak = 7
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
            WdObj.Selection.InsertBreak (wdPageBreak)
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            WB.Close SaveChanges:=False
            fileName = Dir()
        Loop
        Dim fname As String
        fname = "Converted and Combined.docx"
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        With WdObj
            .ChangeFileOpenDirectory "C:\Charts\" & vFile & "\"
            .ActiveDocument.SaveAs fileName:=fname
        End With
        With WdObj
            .ActiveDocument.Close
            .Quit
        End With
        Set WdObj = Nothing
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Upvoted for a comprehensive answer.